# how to check sql version in wix

Tags: wix

Is there any way to find the sql server is 64 bit or 32 bit in machine using wix.
  I am building the wix in visual studio 2010.Based on configuration the installer will install. At install time it will check sql is 64 or 32. If OS is 64bit but 32 sql is installed my installer will install.

Thanks,
Rajeev Kumar.

Comment: Do you need to perform different actions for 32-bit and 64-bit SQL Server? Or you just want to do something only when the 32-bit version is installed, ignoring the 64-bit version?

Comment: if i build the installer in 32bit configuration and trying to install in 64 bit sql server machine i need to pop-up a message and stop  the installation. Same for 64 bit also, if i try to install in 32 bit sql server installed machine i need to stop.

Answer (score 0):

To detect if the target machine is 32-bit or 64-bit you can use [VersionNT64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. This property can be used as a [launch condition](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_launchconditions.htm) to stop the 32-bit package from installing on a 64-bit machine. A 64-bit package cannot run on a 32-bit machine and is stopped automatically.

For detecting SQL Server there are multiple approaches. For example you can search for registry values or use a custom action. Perhaps this article will help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/07/29/682254.aspx

Comment: thanks Cosmin for replying, but for my scenario if i build in 32 bit configuration and installing in 64bit machine having sql32 bit version my installer should be install. But when we try to install 64bit sql my installer should not be installed. I am new to wix can provide custom action code for registry search.By the way i am writing the code in merge module.